# Problema de Codificação em Python

Tags: python, codificação-de-caracteres, web-scraping, utf-8, encode

Estou tentando puxar as hashtags utilizadas em alguns perfis do Instagram utilizando o código:

```
   import pandas as pd
   import requests
   import re

   req = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/globorural/")

   texto = req.text

   pattern = re.compile(r'#[\w\\]*')

   lista_hashtags = pattern.findall(texto)

   print(lista_hashtags)


['#ffffff',
 '#262626',
 '#globorural',
 '#c7c7c7',
 '#globorural',
 '#agronegocio',
 '#corteva',
 '#publi',
 '#parceriapaga',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#Agro',
 '#Campo',
 '#Rural',
 '#GloboRural',
 '#Cannabis',
 '#RevistaGloboRural',
 '#Edi\\u00e7\\u00e3oDeNovembro',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#Cenoura',
 '#Horta',
 '#Mossor\\u00f3',
 '#EngenhariaAgr\\u00f4noma',
 '#MulheresNoAgro',
 '#GloboRural',
 '#VidaNoCampo',
 '#Rural',
 '#Agro',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#Ovelhas',
 '#Caprinos',
 '#MulheresNoAgro',
 '#GloboRural',
 '#VidaNoCampo',
 '#Rural',
 '#Agro',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#Braqui\\u00e1ria',
 '#Plantio',
 '#Almenara',
 '#MinasGerais',
 '#GloboRural',
 '#VidaNoCampo',
 '#Rural',
 '#Agro',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#receitadocampo',
 '#minhareceitanaGR',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#Cavalos',
 '#Equinos',
 '#PasseioACavalo',
 '#GloboRural',
 '#VidaNoCampo',
 '#Rural',
 '#Agro',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#Agronomia',
 '#MulheresDoAgro',
 '#GloboRural',
 '#VidaNoCampo',
 '#Rural',
 '#Agro',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#Brasil',
 '#China',
 '#Bolsonaro',
 '#XiJiping',
 '#Agro',
 '#Campo',
 '#GloboRural',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#Bovinocultura',
 '#Pecu\\u00e1ria',
 '#Leite',
 '#MedicinaVeterin\\u00e1ria',
 '#BomDespacho',
 '#MinasGerais',
 '#GloboRural',
 '#VidaNoCampo',
 '#Rural',
 '#Agro',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#receitasdocampo',
 '#minhareceitanaGR',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#VidaNoCampo',
 '#GloboRural',
 '#Rural',
 '#Agro',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR',
 '#M\\u00e1quinasAgr\\u00edcolas',
 '#M\\u00e1quinasPesadas',
 '#VidaNoCampo',
 '#GloboRural',
 '#Rural',
 '#Agro',
 '#T\\u00f4naGR']
```

Mas estou tendo problemas na conversão de alguns caracteres, como ç (\u00e7) ou ô (\u00f4). Qual a melhor forma de resolver esse problema, utilizando algum tipo especial de encoding ou substituindo os valores que não foram convertidos corretamente com um replace ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/422208/edit) e traduza a pergunta.

Comment: Acho que a barra reversa dupla é um problema. \\u00f4 é a string '\u00f4', enquanto \u00f4 é a letra acentuada "ô".

Answer (score 0):

Da documentação do Request: [documentação request](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)

É possível alterar a formatação:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')

r.encoding
>>> 'utf-8'
r.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
```

A pergunta foi respondida originalmente em:
[python requests.get() returns improperly decoded text instead of UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203397/python-requests-get-returns-improperly-decoded-text-instead-of-utf-8)